# Решение проблемы кодировки UTF-8 в виде переменной на Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8

Всем доброе время суток! Только начал учиться программировать и дошёл до темы записи/чтения в файл. При чтении файла с русским языком внутри в консоли отображаются кракозябры (нарушение кодировки). Решаю проблему таким образом:

```
import _locale 
_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['ru', 'cp866'])
```

Вопрос в следующем - можно ли в Windows как-нибудь добавить переменную, чтобы не нужно было каждый раз писать данную строку? Или принято каждый раз вызывать в файле? Мой первый пост!

Comment: На всякий случай: если read () используете, то там utf-8 опционально есть - можно указать. По Windows - не скажу.

Comment: Разные файлы могут иметь разные кодировки. Правильное решение — явно указывать желаемую кодировку в параметре `encoding` при вызове `open`. Вывод же строк в консоль — это отдельная проблема, которая не имеет к файлам никакого отношения. Кодировка консоли не обязана совпадать с кодировками файлов

Comment: Понял, просто хотелось немного универсальности. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @Pr1nkos как раз указание конкретной кодировки при открытии файла - это универсальный вариант, а изменение `_getdefaultlocale` - костыль, так никто не делает.